# showing loading image still shows "browser loading image" icon

Tags: jquery, image, load, background, transparent

i have this code running to load my images all asynch and show a ajax loading image until the real image is downloaded.

```
 $('img.loadable-image').css('background', 'transparent url(/images/ajax-loader1.gif) no-repeat center center')
$('img.loadable-image').load(function() { $(this).css('background', ''); });
```

this works in that it shows my ajax loading icon until the images is downloaded but it also shows the background as well

here is my original image html:

```
<img class="loadable-image" src="mysite.com/validimage.jpg" border="0" height="50" width="50">
```

here is a screenshot of what i get:

[alt text http://img820.imageshack.us/img820/3289/ajaxload.png](http://img820.imageshack.us/img820/3289/ajaxload.png)

as you can see on the left, you see the little ajax loader but also see the missing image square around it.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/objects.html#h-13.2, which defines that an `<img>` tag must have the `src` attribute.

The missing square will be due the `src` attribute of the `<img>` tag.  If it's not set to a valid image URL, you'll get the "broken image" frame.  Set the src instead of the background (or set it to a transparent image) or change it to a `<span>` element instead of an `<img>` element.

Not valid, no `src` attribute == "broken image" icon:

```
<img alt="" style="width:50px; height:50px; background-image:url(bg.gif)" />
```

valid, with `src` attribute:

```
<img alt="" src="transparent.gif" 
     style="width:50px; height:50px; background-image:url(bg.gif)" />
```

---

After your edit, I can see you're doing it correctly, the problem is the image taking a long time to download.  In that case, you have a few options:

- If you have control over the images, [make them load progressively](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/12/progressive-image-rendering.html) (save GIF/PNG as interlaced, JPEG as progressive).
- If you don't have control over the images, wrap the img hidden in a span, apply the background image to the span element and show the image when the load event fires.

Ex:

```
<span class="loadable-image-container">
    <img class="loadable-image" src="mysite.com/validimage.jpg" 
        border="0" height="50" width="50">
</span>
```

jQuery, something like:

```
$('img.loadable-image-container')
    .css('background', 
      'transparent url(/images/ajax-loader1.gif) no-repeat center center')
    .children().css('visibility', 'hidden');

$('img.loadable-image').load(function() { 
    $(this)
        .css('visibility', 'visible')
        .parent().css('background', ''); 
});
```

Comment: @Andy E's head - can you clarify with an example.  i dont quite follow as i do have transparent set

Comment: @ooo: Updated my answer with more detail.  In short, your images require that the `src` attribute is present and points to a valid image url.

Comment: @Andy E's head - i have updated my question with my image html.  I DO have a valid image in the src . . this is the large image that takes a long time to load.  please advise

Comment: @ooo: sorry, I should have realised that from your question having the `load` event handler :-) I've updated my answer again, see the bottom.

Comment: @Andy E's head - no problem. Given that I dont have control over the images, can you clarify what you mean by "apply the background image to the span element and show the image when the load event fires"